# After update trigger gets fired when BULK INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 tables, the first is the original, and the second is a log of the updates made on the first.

I execute a code in c # that performs a bulk insert os a DataTable in the original table:

```
using (var bulkCopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(conexion))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Original";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tab);
}
```

and in the Original table i have a AFTER UPDATE Trigger to copy modified data from the Original table to the log table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CreateVersionArchiveRow]
   ON  [dbo].[Original]
  AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.Original_LOG

   SELECT *, getdate()
   FROM deleted;
   END
```

The problem is that when i execute the bulk COPY (ONLY  FROM C#, IF EXECUTE FROM SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO TRERE IS NO PROBLEM) the trigger is fired and copy all the data from the Original table to the log table.And what i want is to copy the old data from the Oginal table to the log when i excute an UPDATE, not when i excute a BULK INSERT

I don´t know what i´m doing wrong

Comment: What was your question here exactly? What is your desired result?

Comment: What i expect is only obtain the old data when i execute an update on the Oginal table

Comment: I just tried to replicate. Worked fine for me. May be you have some different trigger that was once created for "after insert". That's the only explanation the comes to my mind.

Comment: Is the only trigger in the DataBase, in fact if i delete this trigger the log table reamins empty.This only occur when bulk insert from C#, if i do Bulk insert from SQL Server Management Studio there is no problem, all works fine, so the problema is in the C# bulk Copy